# Laravel validation uses eloquent or raw query

Tags: validation, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a question related to laravel validation, My question is when we apply rules like unique or exists, validator query through eloquent model or execute raw query? I am using Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer of my question. According to my investigation Validators run query through Query builder, and by default query builder uses default connection, If you want change the connection, you can through following code.

```
    $verifier = \App::make('validation.presence');
    $verifier->setConnection('other_connection_name');
    $validation = $this->validator->make($data, static::$rules);
    $validation->setPresenceVerifier($verifier);
    if($validation->fails()) throw new ValidationException($validation->messages());
```